# Best way to refer to spreadsheet data by header name in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have this data that is coming from a spreadsheet:

```py
data = [
  ['Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C'],
  ['Value A2', 'Value B2', 'Value C2'],
  ['Value A3', 'Value B3', 'Value C3'],
  ['Value A4', 'Value B4', 'Value C4'],
  ...
]
```

The data has about 15 columns and grow to hundreds of rows, but never thousands. When looping through this table in Python, what's the most efficient way to refer to a cell by the column header name?

This is my current solution, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this, for example using native Python 3 methods without having to import an external module like pandas:

```py
# Convert data to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=data[0])
# Strip out header row
df = df.iloc[1:]
# Loop through rows
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  print(row['Column A'], row['Column C'])
```

(I've read it's a [no-no](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/452587) to iterate over dataframes, but since I'm not dealing with such a big dataset I value readability over other more exotic solutions.)

Comment: One of the nice features of python is that you shouldn't have to access values by col and row individually. I understand there may be reasons to do so but if you could explain what you're trying to accomplish there may be a faster and easier way.

Comment: @JesseSealand There's a spreadsheet I don't manage, and they can rearrange the columns (but not rename them), hence I need to access the data by column name and not index. For each row I need to call another API using the values in some of the columns. This API does not accept bulk updates, so I need to call it row-by-row. This API also has a rate limit, so I'll need to use `sleep()` for each iteration to ensure I stay within the rate limit.

Comment: Both solutions here should work equally well. Your dataframe sounds like it's small so shouldn't be an issue either way. If you get into larger datasets, I would definitely start using apply because it'll keep memory using very low and process much more quickly. For now, it sounds like you have several options here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the zip function to ensure that each row's values are associated with the correct headers, creating a dictionary for each row.

```
  data = [
      ['Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C'],
      ['Value A2', 'Value B2', 'Value C2'],
      ['Value A3', 'Value B3', 'Value C3'],
      ['Value A4', 'Value B4', 'Value C4'],
      # ... (you can add more rows as needed)
    ]
    
    # Get headers and data separately
    headers, *rows = data
    
    # Convert rows to list of dictionaries
    dict_rows = [dict(zip(headers, row)) for row in rows]
    
    # Loop through rows
    for row in dict_rows:
        print(row['Column A'], row['Column C'])
```

Comment: Thank you, this was just what the doctor ordered ^^.  Not only was I able to remove pandas dependency but it executed at least 2x faster than my own code.